# Why doesn't my Deep Q Network master a simple Gridworld (Tensorflow)? (How to evaluate a Deep-Q-Net)

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, q-learning

I try to familiarize myself with Q-learning and Deep Neural Networks, currently try to implement [Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf).

To test my implementation and play around with it, I tought I try a simple gridworld. Where i have a N x N Grid and start in the top left corner and finishes at the bottom right. The possible actions are: left, up, right, down.

Even though my implementation has become very similar to [this](https://github.com/asrivat1/DeepLearningVideoGames/blob/master/deep_q_network.py)(hope its a good one) it dosn't seem to learn anything. Looking at the total steps it needs to finish(I guess the average would be aroung 500 with a gridsize of 10x10, but there also very low and high values), it seams more random than anything else to me.

I tried it with and without convolutional layers and played around with all the parameters but to be honest, I've no idea if something with my implementation is wrong or it needs to train longer(I let it train for quite a time) or what ever. But at least it seams to converge, here the plot of the loss value one training session:

[image: Loss image]

So what is the problem in this case?

But also and maybe more importantly how can I "debug" this Deep-Q-Nets, in supervised training there are training, test and validation sets and for example with precision and recall it is possible to evaluate them. What options do I have for unsupervised learning with Deep-Q-Nets, so that the next time maybe I can fix it myself?

Finally here is the code:

This is the network:

```
ACTIONS = 5

# Inputs
x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, 10, 10, 4])
y = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None])
a = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, ACTIONS])

# Layer 1 Conv1 - input
with tf.name_scope('Layer1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([8,8,4,8])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([8])    
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv1, 5)+b_conv1)

# Layer 2 Conv2 - hidden1 
with tf.name_scope('Layer2'):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([2,2,8,8])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([8])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2, 1)+b_conv2)
    h_conv2_max_pool = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Layer 3 fc1 - hidden 2
with tf.name_scope('Layer3'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([8, 32])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([32])
    h_conv2_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv2_max_pool, [-1, 8])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_conv2_flat, W_fc1)+b_fc1)

# Layer 4 fc2 - readout
with tf.name_scope('Layer4'):
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([32, ACTIONS])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([ACTIONS])
    readout = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2)+ b_fc2

# Training
with tf.name_scope('training'):
    readout_action = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(readout, a), reduction_indices=1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - readout_action))
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-6).minimize(loss)

    loss_summ = tf.scalar_summary('loss', loss)
```

And here the training:

```
# 0 => left
# 1 => up
# 2 => right
# 3 => down
# 4 = noop

ACTIONS = 5
GAMMA = 0.95
BATCH = 50
TRANSITIONS = 2000
OBSERVATIONS = 1000
MAXSTEPS = 1000

D = deque()
epsilon = 1

average = 0
for episode in xrange(1000):
    step_count = 0
    game_ended = False

    state = np.array([0.0]*100, float).reshape(100)
    state[0] = 1

    rsh_state = state.reshape(10,10)
    s = np.stack((rsh_state, rsh_state, rsh_state, rsh_state), axis=2)

    while step_count < MAXSTEPS and not game_ended:
        reward = 0
        step_count += 1

        read = readout.eval(feed_dict={x: [s]})[0]

        act = np.zeros(ACTIONS)
        action = random.randint(0,4)
        if len(D) > OBSERVATIONS and random.random() > epsilon:
            action = np.argmax(read)
        act[action] = 1

        # play the game
        pos_idx = state.argmax(axis=0)
        pos = pos_idx + 1

        state[pos_idx] = 0
        if action == 0 and pos%10 != 1: #left
            state[pos_idx-1] = 1
        elif action == 1 and pos > 10: #up
            state[pos_idx-10] = 1
        elif action == 2 and pos%10 != 0: #right
            state[pos_idx+1] = 1
        elif action == 3 and pos < 91: #down
            state[pos_idx+10] = 1
        else: #noop
            state[pos_idx] = 1
            pass

        if state.argmax(axis=0) == pos_idx and reward > 0:
            reward -= 0.0001

        if step_count == MAXSTEPS:
            reward -= 100
        elif state[99] == 1: # reward & finished
            reward += 100
            game_ended = True
        else:
            reward -= 1


        s_old = np.copy(s)
        s = np.append(s[:,:,1:], state.reshape(10,10,1), axis=2)

        D.append((s_old, act, reward, s))
        if len(D) > TRANSITIONS:
            D.popleft()

        if len(D) > OBSERVATIONS:
            minibatch = random.sample(D, BATCH)

            s_j_batch = [d[0] for d in minibatch]
            a_batch = [d[1] for d in minibatch]
            r_batch = [d[2] for d in minibatch]
            s_j1_batch = [d[3] for d in minibatch]

            readout_j1_batch = readout.eval(feed_dict={x:s_j1_batch})
            y_batch = []

            for i in xrange(0, len(minibatch)):
                y_batch.append(r_batch[i] + GAMMA * np.max(readout_j1_batch[i]))

            train.run(feed_dict={x: s_j_batch, y: y_batch, a: a_batch})

        if epsilon > 0.05:
            epsilon -= 0.01
```

I appreciate every help and ideas you may have!

Comment: My first instinct is the layers of convolutions and max pooling causes the agent to lose detail in the location of grids/objects/players, something of importance in a gridworld. Possibly try using a mean pool instead of max pool?

Comment: See my awnser but anyway thanks nice to have some more insides but IT might ne worth a try to See some Time :)

Comment: Good question, I'm struggling the same issue for about 5 weeks and cannot find out what's wrong there. The network is converged by checking the loss values but the reward of 100 steps still too low.  May be I need to do more job on debugging DQN, simplify the network is a choice (I just add too many things into the network: CNNs / Duel-DQN / Double DQN ...).

Answer (score 6):

For those interested, I ajusted the parameters and the model further but the biggest improvment was switching to a simple feed forward network with 3 Layers and about 50 neurons in the hidden layer. For me it then converged in a pretty decent time.

Btw further tips for debuggin are appreciated!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the final code.  Can you update your post plz!

Comment: I probably could, but the last guy asking for the code deleted his comment before i even could post the code on github. So I'm not sure you feel me... ? Don't wanna do homework for others or post something that just gets copy pasted.

Comment: Just sayn' so many people publish their findings for free, because they profit so much from free material. That's a good habit for academics and developers.

Comment: Thats a good point and under this context I'm happy to share it! =D So I've created a git repository with it, would be happy to see some pull requests and some contributions! - See my new answer for the link.

Answer (score 1):

So it's quite a time ago that i wrote this question but it seams that there is still quite some interest and request for the running code i finally decided to create a github repository

Since it's quite a time ago i wrote it and so on it won't run out of the box, but it shouldn't be that hard to get it running. So here is the deep q network and example i wrote at the time which back then worked, hope you enjoy: [Link to deep q repository](https://github.com/natschz/deepq)

Would be nice to see some contribution and if you fix it and get it running make a pull request!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a simple toy DQN without CNN layers, and it works. Here are some findings during my implementation , hope it will help.

1. According to DeepMind's paper they didn't use max pooling layer, the reason is that the image will become position invariant which is not good for the game. The position of agent is crucial for the information of the game.
   [DQN Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meSbH.jpg)
2. If you want to skip the CNN first use gym environment(Like what I have done for the toy implementation), during my development, here are couple of things I found:

   - Encode your state of environment by one-hot encoding, it will increase the training efficiency.
   - I only use a matrix of weights with [number of state, number of action] shape, to do the matrix multiplication with input one-hot encoded state. No bias, no activation function(It will increase training time, I assume, it never work after I add other layer or anything).

This are two things I found extremely crucial for my implementation to work, I am not fully understand the reason behind it, hope my answer can give you a little bit insight.